# Script to get Windows version and send it by email

Tags: windows, batch-file, telnet

I want to monitor version of Windows on all computers in a domain. So I want to create a .bat file that get the local Windows version and if possible send it via email using telnet command.

I never wrote a script in Windows. So it's difficult for me to start in this area. So any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %%A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %%A
```

Will give you a list of computernames. Put it in a file.

```
 for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %%A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %%A >> Computername.txt
```

Then type to do turned on computers

```
 wmic /node:@"Computername.txt" os get version /format:csv
```